# Different number of columns in query output

Tags: postgresql, pivot

I have two tables Table A and B. Table A has three fields: id (primary key), begin_date, end_date.

This captures when each id started purchasing and when they stopped purchasing. Table B has three fields: id, date, qty, and tracks which id purchased how much quantity on which day. There may be multiple purchases made by the same id, with different quantity, on any day.

Table B does not have any primary key. let n be the maximum difference (measured in days) between begin_date and end_date of any id from table B. What I want is an output like the following, which will capture total qty purchased by each id on day 1 from their begin_date, day2 from their begin_date etc.

Clearly, there will be many NULL values either because (a) not each id made purchases on each of the n days from their begin_date or (b) duration between begin_date and end_date of each id is different. How can this be done in postgresql?

```
id | day1 | day2 | day3 | day4 | ... | day(n-1) | dayn
 1 | 20   | NULL | 30   | 10   | ... | NULL     | NULL
 2 | NULL | 23   | 15   | NULL | ... | 16       | NULL
```

We can probably represent the day number along rows first something like the following and the use crosstab. The following result is just for example and is not related to the output above.

```
id | qty  | day_index
 1 | 20   | 1
 1 | NULL | 1
 1 | 10   | 2
 1 | 3    | 3
 1 | 12   | 3
 1 | 15   | 3
 2 | 1    | 2
```

Here, for id=1, day_index=1 if purchased with first 24 hours from begin_date, day_index=2 if purchased with 24 and 48 hours from begin_date etc. Since n can be potentially very large it should not be done manually. How to get the second type of output? Can we use partition in someway?

Comment: If you want a dynamic number of columns, then you need dynamic SQL.

Comment: I kind of gathered that. However, I am not an expert in postgresql. If anyone can flesh out the details that will be really helpful.

Comment: While this is technically feasible, I would still recommend returning the results as rows instead of columns. You can then manage the presentation in your application.

Comment: read about ```crosstab```. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/tablefunc.html